# Symfony2 cloned routed

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am trying to make 1 resource accessible by 2 different routes:

```
api_v1:
    type:     rest
    prefix:   /api/v1
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

app:
    type:     rest
    prefix:   /
    defaults: { _format: html }
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

But forever reason second route overrides the first. When I debug:router I get:

```
get_products    GET      ANY    ANY  /products.{_format}
post_products   POST     ANY    ANY  /products.{_format}
//etc...
```

But I am expecting

```
get_products    GET      ANY    ANY  /api/v1/products.{_format}
post_products   POST     ANY    ANY  /api/v1/products.{_format}
//etc...

get_products    GET      ANY    ANY  /products.{_format}
post_products   POST     ANY    ANY  /products.{_format}
//etc
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The route collection is just an array of routes with the name as the key so when you set multiple routes with the same name they over write each other.

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix this? I wan't to have different routes for api and  front end app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have 2 routes with the same name. In such cases, the second route overrides the previous defined route with the same name, exactly the behaviour you're describing.

It also seems very wrong to have 2 URLs point to exact the same resource. Use a (permanent) redirect to handle such cases.